# How to read a php POST variable in Java

Tags: java

Is it possible read a POST variable set on a server in this way:

```php
<?php

    $_POST['Val'] = 'Ret_value';

?>
```

I need to do this with a Java client

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you mean here.  POST is a type of **request** - a Java client wouldn't *receive* requests (especially no ones generated by the server), it would create/make requests.  The client will get *responses* from the server which are essentially just plain text, so a value could definitely be extracted from these - though the details depend entirely on what the server is sending.

Comment: @Alessandro: Why you want to do that?

Comment: please re-phrase the question. Is your need is to do the same functionality in java what php code doing here?

Comment: ah, ok, I thought that was possible read the variable 'Val', after a java request. I wanted create a sort of web service

Comment: @Allesandro: What do you mean by "after a Java request"? I agree with @gnanz, I believe you should spell out what you're trying to achieve *much* more detailed, there's something about your terminology that makes me fear you may be heading into a strange direction given what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I don't need to do the same thing in java. I just need a java client that get info from a php server

Comment: I solved using the echo function, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

According to [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is a ***An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.***

Modified POST variables are from what I know not included into the HTTP response. Setting them like in your example does not change anything on the server response.

Therefore what you are trying to do - sending data via `$_POST` from a PHP server to a Java client is not possible.

Comment: You have understood my intention, I realized that is not possible, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

ServletRequest don't have setParameter() method, but it have setAttribute() whom you can use to pass some objects for next filter or servlet.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29